# Pull Down To Refresh (Div)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

## The Question

How could I make it where when you pull `<div id="content">` down, it does a function and shows a div at the top of the screen that says "Pull Down To Refresh"?

I know iScroll does this, but it won't work with what I'm trying to do. It only works with UL's.

Here is my HTML

```
<div id="pullDown"> 
    <span class="pullDownIcon"></span><span class="pullDownLabel">Pull down to refresh...
    </span>
</div>
<div id="content">
    (There is a bunch of items that are loaded in via jquery and php, when you pull down to refresh, I want it to basically react that function.)
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    var refreshCallback = function(loader) {
      setTimeout(function(){
        //loader.finish();

      }, 1000);
    };

    var cancelRefreshing = function() {
    };

    $("#draggable").pulltorefresh({
      async: true,
      // event triggered when refreshing start
      refresh: function(event, finishCallback) {
        element = $(this)
        setTimeout(function(){
          alert("refresh");

          // you must call this function if refreshing process runs asynchronusly
          finishCallback();
        }, 1000);
      },
      abort: function() {
        alert("abort");
      }
    });
  });
  </script>
```

for full Demo [Click Here](https://github.com/funayoi/jquery.mobile.pulltorefresh/blob/master/demo.html)

Comment: Thank you, while it does need some tweaking to achieve what I want. It still delivers.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide with iScroll plugin.

**iScroll 4:** http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4

**Github Page:** https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll

**Demo:** http://cubiq.org/dropbox/iscroll4/examples/pull-to-refresh/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$( "#pullDown" ).on( "dragstart", function( event, ui ) {} );
```

inside the function u can have the ajax call to load the content

```
$("#content").load("<something.php>");
```

that is on the whole

```
$( "#pullDown" ).on( "dragstart", function() {
    $("#content").load("<something.php>");
} );
```

Comment: But will this give it the pull down to refresh that I see that twitter has?